# How can I multiply char with a number?

Tags: java, integer, char, ascii, multiplication

It is my first time using stackoverflow!
I am a beginner and I will try to write my problem as short as possible;

User puts a number e.g `1234`

```
char NUMBER = In.read();
while (NUMBER != '\n') {
    Out.println(NUMBER);    
    NUMBER = In.read();
}
```

The Program will put out the numbers as "1" "2" "3" "4", so far so good.

Now I'd like to multiply these numbers with a number I choose.

When trying this, the program says that it's impossible, because you cannot multiply "char" with "int".

How can I solve this problem? How do I multiply these numbers?

Thank you in advance!

I tried using the ASCII, but that also does not work when trying to multiply.

Comment: There's a method [`Character.getNumericValue(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) that should do the trick.

Comment: Bear in mind that `getNumericValue(char)` may [surprise you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31888001/12567365) - depending on the inputs.

Comment: Also consider Integer.parseInt in case you want to convert the result of combining multiple characters into a number.

Comment: You could cast the char variable: int var = (int) NUMBER; and then do the multiplication.

Comment: But remember that the char variable will take the ASCII value, for example, if the char value is 1 and you multiply it by 5, the result will be 245, because 1 in ASCII is 49(decimal) .

Comment: I believe the generic term for what you're looking to do is "parse". E.g. try searching for "parse number java".

Answer (score 0):

## Code points

While `char` can be made to work for you, that is a legacy data type. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

So I suggest you make a habit of using [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers when working with individual characters.

```
int[] codePoints = "1234".codePoints().toArray() ;
```

Loop each code point. Test if that code point represents a character that is a digit. Change each code point back to text. Parse that text as an integer. Multiply using `Math.multiplyExact` to alert us to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Finally, report result.

```
int multiplicand = 2 ;
for( int codePoint : codePoints ) 
{
    if( Character.isDigit( codePoint ) )
    {
        String digitAsText = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
        int x = Integer.parseInt( digitAsText ) ;
        int y = Math.multiplyExact( x , multiplicand ) ;
        System.out.println( x + " * " + multiplicand + " = " + y) ;
    }
}
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ALw7LG).

```
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 2 = 6
4 * 2 = 8
```

### Shorter code

> I am a beginner and I will try to write my problem as short as possible;

Short code is rarely a wise goal.

Longer code, written with short simple statements, is easier to read, easier to debug, and easier for the compiler to optimize.

But if you insist, here is a single statement that leverages advanced features of Java including streams, lambdas, and method references.

```java
"1234"
        .codePoints()
        .filter( Character :: isDigit )
        .mapToObj( Character :: toString )
        .map( Integer :: valueOf )
        .map( ( Integer integer ) -> Math.multiplyExact( integer , 2 ) )
        .forEach( System.out :: println );
```

This single-statement code involves [auto-boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)). So this code may run a tiny bit slower than the longer code above.

When run:

```
2
4
6
8
```